# What is the difference between [...arr, addThisElement], and arr.push(addThisElement) when using useState in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

Could someone please explain the difference between this:

```js
const arr = users;

arr.push({ firstName, email })

setUsers((prevState) => arr)
```

and this:

```js
setUsers(prevState => [...prevState, { firstName, email }])
```

Comment: The difference is that `arr === users` but `[ ...users] !== users`. Which means in the first case, when React does that exact comparison, nothing has changed and so the DOM isn't updated properly. But in the second case, React is dealing with a new array, so it works as intended. Note if you do `const arr = users;`, pushing to `arr` also pushes to `users` because you *didn't create a copy*, just a new way to reference the *single existing array*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is references and object equality...

`Array.prototype.push()` mutates the array in place meaning its object reference does not change.

```js
const prevState = [1,2,3];
const nextState = prevState;
nextState.push(4);
nextState === prevState; // true
```

`[...prevState, { firstName, email }]` creates a new array which is not equal to `prevState`.

```js
const prevState = [1,2,3];
const nextState = [...prevState, 4];
nextState === prevState; // false
```

As per React's state change detection rules...

> [Bailing out of a dispatch](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-dispatch)
>
> If you return the same value from a Reducer Hook as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects. (React uses the [`Object.is` comparison algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is#Description).)

Using `.push()` and updating the state to the same value means React will bail out of the re-render and you won't see changes made.

```js
users.push({
  firstName: "Bob",
  email: "bob@example.com"
});
setUsers(users);
```

[image: Edit lucid-williamson-21sejq]

Create a new array and the changes are made visible

```js
setUsers((prev) => [
  ...prev,
  {
    firstName: "Bob",
    email: "bob@example.com"
  }
]);
```

[image: Edit keen-napier-hk5m5i]

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you mutate the reference `arr` adding a user. In the second case you create a completely new array copying all the data from the old one plus adding the new user.

You should use the second case as react compares the state using `Object.is`, which in case of your first case would return `true` as the reference has not changed even if added a new user and therefore ui would not be updated.